# I have a confusing C problem about writing files in reverse

Tags: c, fwrite, fseek

It's my sloppy code that displays a text code in reverse. Idk why the code activates with i>=-1, not i>=0. fseek(fp,-1,SEEK_SET) and fseek(fp,0,SEEK_SET) should derive NULL and first letter of fp, not first letter and second letter of fp... Plus, I can't notice the difference between fseek(fp,-1,SEEK_CUR) and fseek(fp,i,SEEK_SET), but the latter one only activates. The former one only results the last letter of the file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    FILE *fp=fopen("words.txt","r");
    fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END);
    int size=ftell(fp);
    char *buffer=malloc(sizeof(size+1)); //measuring length
    memset(buffer,0,size+1);
    for(int i=size;i>=-1;i--){ 
        fread(buffer,1,1,fp); 
        fseek(fp,i,SEEK_SET); //it doesn't work while fseek(fp,-1,SEEK_CUR);
        fwrite(buffer,sizeof(char),1,stdout);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    free(buffer);
}
```

words.txt

```
Hello, world!
```

result with  i>=-1,i>=0.

```
!dlorw, olle //-1
!dlorw, olleH //0
```

result with fseek(fp,-1,SEEK_CUR), fseek(fp, i ,SEEK_SET)

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!! //when CUR(last letter*len of file)
!dlrow, olleH //when SET
```

Comment: OT: `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` should be before the `#include`s. If you put it after, it has no effect.

Comment: Looks like you're using Windows. `fseek()` on a text file is only usable in a few cases described [in the Microsoft C Runtime documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fseek-fseeki64?view=msvc-170).

Comment: The `for(int i=size;i>=-1;i--)` will make `size + 2` loops. And the file position requested by `fseek(fp, -1, SEEK_SET);` does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues:

First of all

```
malloc(sizeof(size+1))
```

should be

```
malloc(size+1)
```

The `sizeof` operator gives you the size of its argument which is the size of an `int` on your platform (which is most likely 4 or 8).

But you don't need `buffer` anyway because you only read one char at a time, so a fixed buffer of size 1 is good enough.

Then your for loop is wrong. The very first fread will try reading beyond the end of the file because of the previous `fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END)`.

This would be correct:

```
for (int i = size - 1; i >= -1; i--) {
  fseek(fp, i, SEEK_SET);
  fread(buffer, 1, 1, fp);
  fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), 1, stdout);
}
```

Using `fseek(fp, -1, SEEK_CUR)` it's slightly more complicated:

```
fseek(fp, -1, SEEK_CUR);
for (int i = size -1; i > -1; i--) {
  fread(buffer, 1, 1, fp);
  fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), 1, stdout);
  fseek(fp, -2, SEEK_CUR);  // you need -2 here for compensating
                            // the 1 char read with fread
}
```

---

But anyway the most efficient (and simplest) method to achieve what you want would be to read the whole file into `buffer` with a single fread and then simply display the charcacter in buffer from the end to the beginning. I leave this as an exercise for you.